# Construct a function that is only discontinuous at every point in an open interval

Tags: analysis, continuity

I have to deal with a problem.

Suppose $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ ($a < b$). Prove that there is a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is only discontinuous at every point in $(a,b)$.

This means I have to construct a function $f$ such that $f$ is continuous at every point in $(-\infty,a] \cup [b,\infty)$ and is not continuous at every point in $(a,b)$.

Here is my attempt:

If $a,b$ are rational, we can consider $f$ defined by
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lll}
&0 &\text{ if } &x < a \\ 
&(x-a)(x-b) &\text{ if } &x \in \mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b] \\
&0 &\text{ if } &x \in \mathbb{Q}^c\cap[a,b] \\
&0 &\text{ if } &x > b\\
\end{array}
\right. $$

The same argument for $a,b$ are irrational.

But when $a$ is rational and $b$ is irrational. My function cannot work.

Does anyone have any idea? Please give me some hints. I highly appreciate it.

Comment: When any of them is irrational why not adding it to the second interval and remove them from the third interval

Comment: Then $f$ cannot be continuous at $a$, for example. You mean $f(x) = x-a$ when $x$ is in $[a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = x-b$ when $x$ is in $[a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}^c$?

Comment: You do not need to change anything, if $a$ is irrational then $f(a)=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)=0$ still holds

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I'm silly.

Comment: To deal with $x$ rational, Then for any $\epsilon>0$ choose $\delta =\frac{\epsilon}{|b-a|}$ then whenever $|x-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{|b-a|}$ thus $|x-a||x-b|<|x-a||b-a| < \epsilon$

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is pretty good.

To deal with the inconsistency between $a$ and $b$, we can split the interval $[a,b]$ in half, constructing each part separately.

Here is an example.
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
&x -a &\text{ if } x\in (a, \frac{a+b}2),\ (x-a)\in \Bbb Q\\ 
&x-b &\text{ if } x\in (\frac{b+a}2,b),\ (x-b)\in\Bbb Q\\
&0 &\text{ for all other } x \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Sorry, I misread your function.

Comment: @FactorY, is it clear now?

Comment: Yes but I need to check that the function satisfies all my needs.